# MUI Slider Component: different colour thumbs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, slider

MUI has a slider component: https://mui.com/material-ui/react-slider/
I'm currently using it to allow users to pick a value range (so my slider has two thumbs)
MUI multi thumb slider docs: https://codesandbox.io/s/gptppq?file=/demo.js

The slider thumb can be styled as shown here: https://codesandbox.io/s/359l9t?file=/demo.tsx:3809-3812

My question: how do i make the two thumbs have a different style/color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can style each thumb of the MUI [Range Slider](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-slider/) individually by targeting the `data-index` prop via [CSS attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).  For example:

```
<Slider
  value={value}
  onChange={handleChange}
  sx={{
    "& .MuiSlider-thumb": {
      "&[data-index='0']": {
        backgroundColor: "pink"
      },
      "&[data-index='1']": {
        backgroundColor: "yellow"
      }
    }
  }}
/>
```

Which produces:

[image: example of individually styled thumbs]

***Working CodeSandbox:*** https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-individually-styled-thumbs-c5m2q9

Comment: thanks I can't believe it's that easy.
one more question: would it be possible to also have multiple track colours?
for example the track before the pink thumb to be pink, the track between them to be green and the track after the yellow thumb to be yellow?

Comment: @CodePal You're welcome! Yes that's totally possible -- is this what you're looking for? https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-split-colored-track-requested-fs7jd3